# Minecraft fill command cobblestone slabs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm doing a big project and I want to use the fill command to make multiple cobblestone slabs. However when I start typing the command cobblestone slabs is not an option I can choose. I can make it out of all kinds of other slabs but I really want cobblestone slabs.

Comment: Which version of MCJE are you playing? 1.12- has different commands than 1.13+.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to give an accurate answer without knowing what version you are playing in! but if you are playing in 1.13+ this command works:

```
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~10 ~ ~10 minecraft:cobblestone_slab[type=bottom,waterlogged=false]
```

If you want you can also add `replace minecraft:air` at the end to only replace a specific block!

Next time you ask a question, let us know commands you have tested and what version you are playing in.

Answer (score -1):

The ID isn't actually `minecraft:cobblestone_slab`. It is actually the 3rd data type (or damage value) of `minecraft:stone_slab`, so `minecraft:stone_slab 3` would be your block ID.